# run configurations in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I am trying to run simple java program in eclipse, but it show me the following:
[image]

Unfortunately, cant figure out how to change run configuration in eclipse.
Thank you in advance!

ADDED:

Thats my run configurations.
I do not need tomcat at all for running simple program.
I trien to create new java applet or java application - but cant apply it.

[image]

Comment: You aren't launching a 'simple Java program' here. How **exactly** are you running the program?

Comment: Not so simple if you have tagged "applet". Can you show us the details? Maybe you do not have Tomcat correctly installed in your system or linked correctly with your Eclipse.

Comment: Menu: Run -> Run Configurations...

Comment: I added new information. Thanks

Comment: @greg-449, I am just clicking the button "run", but this message appears

Comment: Right-click on the java file that you want to execute. In the emerging panel that appears select "Run As" followed by "Java Application".

Comment: @ RubioRic, yes, I am doing that, but have only one option - run configuration. There is nothing about "java application"

Comment: Have your class got a main method with this signature "public static void main(String[] args)"?

Comment: Clicking 'run' just runs the last thing you ran, it does not run the current Java program. The run configuration you show is for running Tomcat not running a simple Java program.

Comment: @Alex you need that exact method to run a java class. Eclipse detects its presence allowing you to launch as java application or not.

Comment: Yes, I skipped main method. Thank you! So stupid mistake(

Comment: @Alex Glad to help. :-)